# Riverpod Provider to pass down FireStore document Id to other pages in app flow

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I have an archaic solution for my problem, but it's quickly become cumbersome and not as robust. I want to switch to a riverpod provider and am studying how to do so, but I want to put this question out there at the same time. For simplicity, my app is similar to BlaBlaCar. Lots of trips listed, and then users can request to be picked up. The general flow goes like this:

[image]

To call the same document ID from Firestore, my solution has been just to pass a detailDocument parameter over and over. In my trips page, I have a streambuilder that displays the document:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> tripStreamBuilder() {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: tripStream.snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
        }
        return ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data =
                document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return Card(
              child: ListTile(
                // leading: Text((data['departureDate']).toString()),
                title: Text('From ${data['departure']}'),
                subtitle: Text('To ${data['arrival']}'),
                trailing: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text((data['departureDate']).toString()),
                      Text('Leaving at ${data['departureTime']}'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
                      .push(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => TripDetails(
                                detailDocument: document,
                              )));
                },
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
```

From here, I just keep making detailDocument a parameter. For exmaple in my trip details:

```
class TripDetails extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const TripDetails({super.key, required this.detailDocument});
  final DocumentSnapshot detailDocument;
```

And jointrip class:

```
class JoinTrip extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const JoinTrip({
    super.key,
    required this.detailDocument,
  });
  final DocumentSnapshot detailDocument;
```

So my question is how can I pass the document ID into a riverpod provider? And one that gets disposed and reset as users click on different trips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't pass the `id` of your document to pages. You can check [this example](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading#using-refwatch-to-observe-a-provider) from the official documentation.

In you case, you can have a provider that saves the `id`. So whenever you need to fetch or do something about the same id, you watch its value and when you need to change it, you can change the id in that provider.

Let's say we have two providers as follow:

```dart
// id provider
final tripIdProvider = StateProvider<String?>((ref) => null);

// Another provider fetching the document for an id
final tripProvider = Provider((ref) {
  final id = ref.watch(tripIdProvider);
  // code to call the Firebase and returning the result for instance.
});
```

`tripIdProvider` has the latest clicked `id`, and `tripProvider` will watch this `id` and updates and fetch the new values if the `id` changes. It fetches the document of that id from the Firebase.

Now if user clicks another object having another id, in the callback of pressing/tapping that object, you can do something like this:

```dart
...
onPressed:(){
 ref.read(tripIdProvider.notifier).state = id;
}
```

This will change the `id` and because `tripProvider` is `watch`ing that providers' value, it will be triggered again and will fetch new data for the new `id`.

It's also good to check [stateNotifier](https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/state_notifier_provider/).

Comment: Do you think this is a better solution then a StateNotifierProvider? I copied my code in another answer

Comment: Both works and depends to your need. I usually use state notifier and for example use the `family` feature and pass the `id` to it and then return an exact model(Class) I need out of it as the `state` and not directly using `documentSnapshot`.

Comment: @NooN3rd thanks for the feedback, still getting the hang of it

Comment: @HunterBooks You're welcome. You can learn more about provider and Riverpod from [Andrea](https://codewithandrea.com/tutorials/)'s blog. He has several good tutorials about it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so not sure if this is the best solution, but I ended up making a StateNotifierProvider out of the DocumentSnapshot class from Firestore.

```
class DocumentSnapshotNotifier extends StateNotifier<DocumentSnapshot?> {
  DocumentSnapshotNotifier() : super(null);

  DocumentSnapshot? get documentSnapshot => state;

  set documentSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot? documentSnapshot) {
    state = documentSnapshot;
  }

  void updateDocumentSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot? documentSnapshot) {
    state = documentSnapshot;
  }
}

final documentProvider = StateNotifierProvider<
    DocumentSnapshotNotifier,
    DocumentSnapshot?>((ref) => DocumentSnapshotNotifier());
```

Then once a user clicks on a trip, I pass the value to the provider via

```
  onTap: () {
                  ref
                      .read(documentProvider.notifier)
                      .updateDocumentSnapshot(document);
```

Then I can just call it for whatever field in the doc I need.

```
Center(
                child: Text(
                    'Departure Place: ${ref.read(documentProvider)!['departure']}')),
          ),
          Center(
              child:
                  Text('Arrival Place: ${ref.read(documentProvider)!['arrival']}')),
          Center(
              child: Text(
                  'Departure Date: ${ref.read(documentProvider)!['departureDate']}'))
```

It's working for now...

Comment: You don't need a `get` to access the `state`. You have access to it by `ref.watch(documentProvider)` for instance.

Comment: For providers in order to update the UI, you'd better use `watch` once and use its state in different places.
`final myState = ref.watch(documentProvider);`

Comment: @NoobN3rd that makes a lot of sense, good looks